# How do I remove specific elements using an jQuery .each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, each

Assume I have an HTML document containing:

```
<form id = "my_form">
    <input type = "text" />
    <input type = "text" />
    <input type = "text" />
    <button type = "button" onclick = "removeGoodInputs()">Do the job</button>
</form>
```

I want to get rid of the inputs values which satisfy some condition (given in my JS). I have tried creating my `removeGoodInputs()` function (as below), but this removes all inputs from the form. How can I resolve this issue?

```
function removeGoodInputs() {
    $("#my_form input").each(function() {
        if(this.attr("value") == 10)
            $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.attr()` is a jQuery method so it can only be called on a jQuery object.   Further, in jQuery `.val()` is the easier way to get the value (a shortcut).

So, this line of your code is not correct:

```
if(this.attr("value") == 10)
```

I would recommend either:

```
if (this.value == "10")      // plain javascript
```

or:

```
if ($(this).val() == "10")   // jQuery
```

Note, I also changed the comparisons to be strings since that is what `.value` returns and it's better to not rely on an automatic type conversion.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HMemp/

Comment: Also it can be `if($(this).attr("value") == 10)`

Comment: @SheikhHeera - yes that is an option, but there's no point in doing that when `.val()` or `.value` are more direct.

Comment: Yes, I agree, just commented because you answered it in such a way using `either` so I thought it should be mentioned too as another option.

Comment: Yeah, the mistakes came as that wasn't the exact sample of my code, just wanted to bring here the key lines. Anyway, the problem was actually the way I had constructed the condition within if-instruction. Still, thanks for help :D

Comment: @user1658414 - so your question does not accurately show what was causing the problem?

Comment: Indeed, the problem was the condition which I wanted to receive a number between 1 and 30 and before that I had a condition that only numbers lower than 1 and greater than 30 passed. I changed lower signs to greater and vice versa but forgot about the logical conjuction. My way of thinking was the same as you guys presented. Anyway thanks for all replies

Answer (score 1):

`attr` is one the methods of jQuery object, you should first convert the DOM object `this` to a jQuery object and then use jQuery methods, `$(this).attr("")`, also you can use `val` method for getting/setting values of form controls instead of `attr` and you don't need `each`, you can use `Attribute Equals Selector`:

```
function removeGoodInputs() {
    $("#my_form input[value='10']").remove();
}
```

`$("#my_form input[value='10']")` selects the inputs that their values are `10`.

- [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("#my_form input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === '10';
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeGoodInputs() {
 $("#my_form input").each(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 10) $(this).remove();
 });
}
```